# Assigning values to a random variable and then finding the Probability Mass Func & CDF.

Tags: probability

I'm new to the idea of random variables and PDFs and CDFs so I have a bit of confusion with how they operate. I have a given example that I am trying to work through but I am a little stuck with how to proceed!

An experiment consists of throwing a fair coin 4 times. Find the frequency function and the cumulative distribution function of the following random variables: (a) the number of heads before the first tail, (b) the number of heads following the first tail, (c) the number of heads minus the number of tails, and (d) the number of tails before the number of heads.

I'm currently working through (a), and here's what I've done so far.

Let X be a random variable, such that:

$$X = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{0 heads before first tail} \\ 
1 & \text{1 head before first tail} \\ 
2 & \text{2 heads before first tail} \\
3 & \text{3 heads before first tail} \\
 \end{cases}$$

Is this a correct random variable for (a)?

I now begin determining the probability mass function (also called frequency function).

$$P(X=0) = 8 / 16 $$

$$P(X=1) = 4 / 16 $$

$$P(X=2) = 2 / 16 $$

$$P(X=3) = 1 / 16 $$

But this confuses me, because of my understanding of the definition of the probability mass function, which is that for each $x_i$ in $X$, $p(x_i) = P(X=x_i)$ and $\sum_i$p($x_i$) = $1$, which you can clearly see that mine do not sum up to 1, which means I either did the probabilities wrong or am I not understanding something. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is  poorly expressed, because as you have noticed, the "number of heads before the first tail" begs the question of "what is $X$ if there **is** no first tail."  I would assign that case to "$4$ heads before the first tail," and now your probabilities will add to one.  Or you could say that this case is "$0$ heads before the first tail," and now $P(X=0)$ becomes $\frac9{16}$, again restoring your faith in addition of probabilities.